# Wordpress Custom Post Type Taxonomy - Get specific content

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, post, taxonomy

I have a website with food products and I have a custom post type called recipes.
What I need to do is to display 3 posts from the recipe-categories attached to the product.
I have created and attached the custom post type to my products but I just can't get it to work!I am kind of lost. I have managed to loop through the recipes and get 3 posts but I don't know how to filter out the categories for the recipes.

Example:

```
-Recipe Categories
Sauce
Spicy
```

Lets say I have a product "Noodle" and I want to show 3 posts from Sauce category. I can't manage to display it. I am always getting posts from every single Recipe Category.

This is my loop to show the 3 posts.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'recipes', 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>


            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">            

              <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                </a>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I have tried to add taxonomy categories to my array arguments but nothing happens!
Here is what i tried to do(with many variations):

```
$mytaxonomy = 'recipe_category';
$myterms = get_the_terms($post, $mytaxonomy);
```

and then I used the same while as above with adding the terms in the array.
Can someone please help me? I am lost and stuck but I need to know why it doesn't work so I can improve myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP_Query also support [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) for getting post by category, give it a try:

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'recipe_category');
$recipe_cat_slug = array();
foreach ($terms as $term)
{
    $recipe_cat_slug[] = $term->slug;
}
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'recipes',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'recipe_category',
            'field' => 'slug', //can be set to ID
            'terms' => $recipe_cat_slug //if field is ID you can reference by cat/term number; you can also pass multiple cat as => array('sauce', 'spicy')
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks good but i need this to be done dynamically. I mean that it needs to check the product's recipe category and pass the term name to the loop you posted! Thank you so much! Didnt know about tax_query

Comment: are you using WooCommerce for product? or it is coming form custom post type? and does your `product` and `recipes` share same category name slug?

Comment: I am using woocommerce and i have attached the taxonomy recipe_categories to both product and recipe

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it. and you want to display post in product details page right?

Comment: Yes i want to display my posts in single product page right before the footer!

Comment: You are a God! I also added random order by so if i add 2 recipe categories it can loop random through all categories. Thank you so much mate! i owe you a big time!